# Finding Pythagorean triplet in array

Tags: java, complexity

We have an integer array as:

```
private int[] arr = {1, 3, 5, 14, 18, 29, 78};
```

We have a function which takes three inputs of the array and checks whether:

```
a * a = b * b + c * c
```

If the function returns `true` then those 3 inputs are stored in an `ArrayList`:

```
private boolean findTriplet(int a, int b, int c) {
    int squareA = a * a;
    int squareB = b * b;
    int squareC = c * c;
    int sum = squareB + squareC;
    if (squareA == sum) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Iterating through the array:

```
 private void getTriplets(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                for (int k = i+j; k < arr.length; k++) {
                    if ((i != k) || (j != k)) {
                        boolean tripResult = findTriplet(arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]);
                        if (tripResult) {
                            tripList.add(new Triplet(arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the above solution the complexity of the program is \$O(n^3)\$.

How can I optimise this solution or get a more flexible complexity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of notes on your code before going into alternative solutions.

- In your `findTriplet` method, you are doing:

  ```
  if (squareA == sum) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
  ```

  which is more concisely expressed as

  ```
  return squareA == sum;
  ```
- Your main `getTriplets` method checks whether `(i != k) || (j != k)`, but this isn't possible by construction: `k` starts at `i+j` so it cannot be equal to `i` or `j`; thus this check can be removed. Also `j` starts at 1 when you could make it start at `j + 1`, which would also get rid of the `i != j` check.

---

You can do this in O(n²) by utilizing a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

The idea is the following:

1. Transform the array into a `TreeSet<Integer>`, where each element will be the squared value of the element in the array. Using a `TreeSet` has the advantage that it sorts the elements ascendingly and allows for fast look-up.
2. For each element in the set, get all the elements greater than it and see if the set contains a third value equal to the sum of those two. This is because, if we look for 3 numbers `a`, `b` and `c` where `a + b = c`, then having both `a` and `b` only leaves the question: does the set contains `a + b`?

A possible implementation is the following:

```
private void getTriplets(int[] arr) {
    NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(); 
    for (int element : arr) {
        set.add(element * element);
    }
    for (Integer a : set) {
        for (Integer b : set.tailSet(a, false)) {
            if (set.tailSet(b, false).contains(a + b)) {
                tripList.add(new Triplet(a, b, a + b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method [`tailSet(element, false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet-E-boolean-) will return a view of the set with all the elements strictly greater than the passed element. [This method runs in constant-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31813139/1743880). In the code above, `a` will loop through all the values of the set, `b` will loop over the values greater than `a` and we see if the set contains `a + b`. If it does then we have found a Pythagorian triplet.

---

This solution does have the overhead of creating a `Set` (so O(n) memory) but it is simple to write.

Another approach with O(1) memory is to keep an array but the approach [is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032765/1743880):

> 1. Sort the array in ascending order. This takes O(n log n).
> 2. Now consider each element `a[i]`. If `a[i]=a[j]+a[k]`, then, since numbers are positive and array is now sorted, `k<i` and `j<i`.
>
>    To find such indexes, run a loop that increases `j` from `1` to `i`, and decreases `k` from `i` to `0` at the same time, until they meet. Increase `j` if `a[j]+a[k] < a[i]`, and decrease `k` if the sum is greater than `a[i]`. If the sum is equal, that's one of the answers, print it, and shift both indexes.
>
>    This takes O(i) operations.
> 3. Repeat step 2 for each index i. This way you'll need totally O(n²) operations, which will be the final estimate.

Step 2 is similar to [finding a given number by summing up integers from 2 sorted arrays](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/118775/95296).

In terms of code, you could have the following:

```
private void getTriplets(int[] arr) {
    int[] squaredArray = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        squaredArray[i] = arr[i] * arr[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(squaredArray);
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int j = 1, k = i;
        while (j < k) {
            int sum = squaredArray[j] + squaredArray[k];
            if (sum < squaredArray[i]) {
                j++;
            } else if (sum > squaredArray[i]) {
                k--;
            } else {
                tripList.add(new Triplet(squaredArray[j], squaredArray[k], squaredArray[i]));
                j++;
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main loop on `i` is performed descendingly since we're looking for two elements whose sum is `squaredArray[i]` (and the array is sorted ascendingly).

Answer (score 3):

You tagged the question with "array", but I think this is the wrong data structure if you want speed: You need to cycle only over a and b, if you can find c² quickly, and this is difficult with arrays, while `Map`s or `Set`s provide typically O(log n) access time.

I used a `TreeMap` here in order to being able to look up the squares quickly, but to recover the original values as well. Note that having the `tailMap` method is crucial for avoiding overhead and duplicates.

```
private static void getTriplets(int[] arr) {
    SortedMap<Integer, Integer> sqr = new TreeMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(n -> sqr.put(n * n, n));
    sqr.forEach((aa, a) -> sqr.tailMap(aa).forEach(
        (bb, b) -> Optional.ofNullable(sqr.get(aa + bb)).ifPresent(
             c -> tripList.add(new Triplet(a, b, c)))
    ));
}
```

Comment: Using `forEach` is generally not a good idea: it is preferable to use a reduce / collect approach that parallelize well. For example, in the first case, it should be `Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(n -> n * n, n -> n));`

Comment: That won't work here, as I need a `SortedMap`. Too bad there is no `Collector` for this.

Comment: Yes, there is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-. You can give a `mapSupplier`. Unfortunately, you also need to give a `mergeFunction` that does nothing since there won't be collisions here... See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004899/java-8-collectors-tomap-sortedmap

Answer (score 2):

Others have proposed some alternatives to your original algorithm and data structure.  I'm going to discuss ways to optimize it instead.

#### `findTriplet`

> ```
> private boolean findTriplet(int a, int b, int c) {
> ```

I'd prefer

```
private boolean isTriplet(int a, int b, int c) {
```

That's a more common name for something that tests for truth.  And this method doesn't search for anything.

> ```
>     int squareA = a * a;
>     int squareB = b * b;
>     int squareC = c * c;
>     int sum = squareB + squareC;
>     if (squareA == sum) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> ```

If the array is sorted ascending, then `c` will be greater than either `a` or `b`.  So

```
    int sum = squareB + squareA;
    if (squareC == sum) {
```

would make more sense.

```
    int squareA = a * a;
    int squareB = b * b;
    int squareC = c * c;
    int sum = squareA + squareB;
    return sum == squareC;
```

The `if` is unnecessary.

```
    int squareA = a * a;
    int squareB = b * b;
    int squareC = c * c;

    return squareA + squareB == squareC;
```

This is simpler.

```
    return a * a + b * b == c * c;
```

Simplest.

#### `getTriplets`

> ```
> private void getTriplets(int[] arr) {
> ```

I'd probably make this

```
private void findTriplets(int[] candidates) {
```

I find `candidates` to be more descriptive than `arr`.  Another option would be `sides`.

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>         for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
>             if (i != j) {
>                 for (int k = i+j; k < arr.length; k++) {
>                     if ((i != k) || (j != k)) {
> ```

The `((i != k) || (j != k))` should be `((i != k) && (j != k))`.  I think that `k = i+j` is also wrong.  Perhaps you wanted `k = 1 + Math.max(i, j)` instead.

There are a couple ways to simplify this.  In general, rather than nesting `if` statements, you can instead do

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < candidates.length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int k = 1 + Math.max(i, j); k < candidates.length; k++) {
                if ((i == k) || (j == k)) {
                    continue;
                }
```

Note that the `||` is now the correct operator, as we took the logical negative of the original expression.

But in this case we have a simpler option.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidates.length; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < candidates.length; k++) {
```

This will check each combination of three elements of the array.  If the array is sorted ascending, this will be sufficient.  It never has the indexes the same, so you don't have to do separate equality checks.

> ```
>                         boolean tripResult = findTriplet(arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]);
>                         if (tripResult) {
> ```

You could simplify this to just

```
                if (isTriplet(candidates[i], candidates[j], candidates[k])) {
```

But we could do even better if the array is sorted.

```
                int comparison = compareTriplet(candidates[i], candidates[j], candidates[k]);
                if (comparison == 0) {
                    tripList.add(new Triplet(candidates[i], candidates[j], candidates[k]));
                }

                if (comparison <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
```

where

```
private boolean compareTriplet(int a, int b, int c) {
    return Integer.compare(a * a + b * b, c * c);
}
```

If the comparison is greater than 0, we can continue.

If the comparison is equal to 0, then we can add the triplet to the list.

If the comparison is less than or equal to 0, then we don't need to continue checking values for the third member of the triplet.  We've either found or passed the point where we could have found the third member.